# dead: predicative or attributive?

Tags: adjectives, usage, predicative-complement, attributives

I know that *dead* is an *adjective*.

however, in two sentences,

1. He is dead
2. Dead man is over there.

I am confused of property of adjective.

It seemed that **1** used as predicative adjective, whereas **2** used as attributive adjective.

Am I right..?

Comment: It can also be a noun (*bring out your dead*) and an adverb (*they are dead tired*).

Comment: Your secoind example is incorrect. It needs the word "The" or "A" at the beginning. This isn't optional.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. *Dead* can be used as a predicative and attributive adjective.  Most adjectives can be used as both a predicative and attributive adjective.

> 1. He is dead

*dead* comes after the linking verb *is* in this sentence, so it is a predicative adjective.

> 2. The dead man is over there.

*Dead* comes before the noun *man* in this sentence, so it is an attributive adjective. An article "The" is also needed for English grammar.

Comment: Yes, although I would point out that *dead man is over there* doesn't seem to be a complete sentence.  Although it could be an example of left-edge deletion ("[The] dead man is over there"), if it's intended as a complete sentence we'd want to repair it somehow; the specific repair would depend on context that we don't have here.